# 18.04 to 18.1 update not doing anything

Tags: upgrade

I went to software & updates and selected notify me of a new ubuntu version for any new version. Then I run Software Updater, it says up to date but there is a new version 18.1 with an upgrade button. I click the button and the window closes, no error and no upgrade. I have restarted, no change, ran again, no change. Is there any known bugs? Should I just use command line? Is the 18.04-18.1 upgrade pretty stable?

Comment: 18.04 is LTS, i.e. you get support for 5 years till 2023, but with 18.10 you would get support for nine months only. My recommendation would be stick to the LTS unless required to move to non LTS.

Comment: Good recommendation, I'm just looking for Gnome updates and theme/etc. I'm okay to upgrade or reinstall again in 9 mo.